# Break someone down

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I came upon this sentence:

> I’m sitting in church, this guy's name's Cliff. He’s born... And then
>   **I just break the guy down** and then I can’t listen.

He is refering to the fact that for him priests are just normal people who tell you what to do because they think they're special and he gets bored listening to them. I know that "break someone down" can mean "dropping someone's confidence" but in this case, I think it makes no sense.

Can anyone explain what this expression means in this context?

Thanks,
Rocío

Comment: I think it means *analyze*, *take apart and analyze the pieces*, *recognize him for what he really is*.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.  Could you tell us where you found this?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the author is trying to say, that the character understood everything about him (analyzed him). Getting deeper understanding of the priest, he read him like a book. 
I also found this meaning on the internet:
Break you down

> Removing the walls and façades we hide behind and getting a deeper
>   understanding of that person. Deeper than that superficial level.

Comment: Could you please provide a citation for this novel sense of “break someone down”?

Comment: is this meaning of 'break you down' your personal interpretation, or there's a reference? In the former case, I am not sure you should put it in block-quotes